# Помогите разобрать странный XML ответ в Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

Вот такой ответ приходит от SOAP-сервиса

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soap:Body>
          <m:ClientITSStatusResponse xmlns:m="http://buhphone.com/PartnerWebAPI2">
             <m:return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Property name="ResultCode" xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core">
                   <Value xsi:type="xs:string">SUCCESS</Value>
                </Property>
                <Property name="ResultData" xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core">
                   <Value xsi:type="ValueTable">
                      <column>
                         <Name>ResultCode</Name>
                         <ValueType>
                            <Type>xs:string</Type>
                            <StringQualifiers>
                               <Length>0</Length>
                               <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
                            </StringQualifiers>
                         </ValueType>
                      </column>
                      <column>
                         <Name>ResultData</Name>
                         <ValueType/>
                      </column>
                      <row>
                         <Value xsi:type="xs:string">SUCCESS</Value>
                         <Value xsi:type="ValueTable">
                            <column>
                               <Name>DateFrom</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                                  <DateQualifiers>
                                     <DateFractions>Date</DateFractions>
                                  </DateQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <column>
                               <Name>DateTo</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                                  <DateQualifiers>
                                     <DateFractions>Date</DateFractions>
                                  </DateQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <column>
                               <Name>ITSLevel</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:string</Type>
                                  <StringQualifiers>
                                     <Length>13</Length>
                                     <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
                                  </StringQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <row>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2019-02-01T00:00:00</Value>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2020-01-31T00:00:00</Value>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:string">PROF</Value>
                            </row>
                         </Value>
                      </row>
                      <row>
                         <Value xsi:type="xs:string">SUCCESS</Value>
                         <Value xsi:type="ValueTable">
                            <column>
                               <Name>DateFrom</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                                  <DateQualifiers>
                                     <DateFractions>Date</DateFractions>
                                  </DateQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <column>
                               <Name>DateTo</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                                  <DateQualifiers>
                                     <DateFractions>Date</DateFractions>
                                  </DateQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <column>
                               <Name>ITSLevel</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:string</Type>
                                  <StringQualifiers>
                                     <Length>13</Length>
                                     <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
                                  </StringQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <row>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2019-04-15T00:00:00</Value>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2020-04-14T00:00:00</Value>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:string">PROF</Value>
                            </row>
                         </Value>
                      </row>
                   </Value>
                </Property>
             </m:return>
          </m:ClientITSStatusResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
```

Интересует, как получить список из:

```
<row>
    <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2019-04-15T00:00:00</Value>
    <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2020-04-14T00:00:00</Value>
    <Value xsi:type="xs:string">PROF</Value>
</row>
```

Где `<row>` будет индексом, а `<Value>` - значениями.

Comment: К soap-ответам лучше относиться не как к XML, а как к soap-ответам, и обрабатывать их соответствующими библиотеками для работы с SOAP.

Comment: В случае с 1С - это отдельная история ) Не подскажите как правильно разобрать именно soap ответ с таким пространством имен?

Comment: Вам просто список получить? У вас структура из row строится: row содержит Value, а Value может содержать row, которые содержат Value

Comment: А я вот когда с соапом работал загружал схемы компановки (xsd чтоль) формировал объекты там какие-то)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Покажу пример парсинга через `lxml` используя xpath-выражения:

```
text = """\
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
       <soap:Body>
          <m:ClientITSStatusResponse xmlns:m="http://buhphone.com/PartnerWebAPI2">
             <m:return xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
                <Property name="ResultCode" xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core">
                   <Value xsi:type="xs:string">SUCCESS</Value>
                </Property>
                <Property name="ResultData" xmlns="http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core">
                   <Value xsi:type="ValueTable">
                      <column>
                         <Name>ResultCode</Name>
                         <ValueType>
                            <Type>xs:string</Type>
                            <StringQualifiers>
                               <Length>0</Length>
                               <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
                            </StringQualifiers>
                         </ValueType>
                      </column>
                      <column>
                         <Name>ResultData</Name>
                         <ValueType/>
                      </column>
                      <row>
                         <Value xsi:type="xs:string">SUCCESS</Value>
                         <Value xsi:type="ValueTable">
                            <column>
                               <Name>DateFrom</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                                  <DateQualifiers>
                                     <DateFractions>Date</DateFractions>
                                  </DateQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <column>
                               <Name>DateTo</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                                  <DateQualifiers>
                                     <DateFractions>Date</DateFractions>
                                  </DateQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <column>
                               <Name>ITSLevel</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:string</Type>
                                  <StringQualifiers>
                                     <Length>13</Length>
                                     <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
                                  </StringQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <row>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2019-02-01T00:00:00</Value>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2020-01-31T00:00:00</Value>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:string">PROF</Value>
                            </row>
                         </Value>
                      </row>
                      <row>
                         <Value xsi:type="xs:string">SUCCESS</Value>
                         <Value xsi:type="ValueTable">
                            <column>
                               <Name>DateFrom</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                                  <DateQualifiers>
                                     <DateFractions>Date</DateFractions>
                                  </DateQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <column>
                               <Name>DateTo</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:dateTime</Type>
                                  <DateQualifiers>
                                     <DateFractions>Date</DateFractions>
                                  </DateQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <column>
                               <Name>ITSLevel</Name>
                               <ValueType>
                                  <Type>xs:string</Type>
                                  <StringQualifiers>
                                     <Length>13</Length>
                                     <AllowedLength>Variable</AllowedLength>
                                  </StringQualifiers>
                               </ValueType>
                            </column>
                            <row>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2019-04-15T00:00:00</Value>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:dateTime">2020-04-14T00:00:00</Value>
                               <Value xsi:type="xs:string">PROF</Value>
                            </row>
                         </Value>
                      </row>
                   </Value>
                </Property>
             </m:return>
          </m:ClientITSStatusResponse>
       </soap:Body>
    </soap:Envelope>
"""
```

Код:

```
def get_xsi_type(node) -> str:
    return node.xpath('@xsi:type', namespaces={'xsi': 'http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'})[0]

def get_text(node) -> str:
    return node.xpath('text()')[0]

from lxml import etree
from collections import OrderedDict

root = etree.fromstring(text)
# print(etree.tostring(root))

NSMAP = {'core': 'http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core'}

result = OrderedDict()

for row in root.xpath('//core:row', namespaces=NSMAP):
    # result[row] = row.xpath('core:Value', namespaces=NSMAP)
    # OR:
    result[row] = row.xpath('*')

print(len(result))

for row, values in result.items():
    # Только простые типы
    if any(get_xsi_type(value) == 'ValueTable' for value in values):
        continue

    print(row)
    for value in values:
        print(f'    type={get_xsi_type(value)}, value={get_text(value)}')

    print()
```

Результат:

```
4
<Element {http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core}row at 0x23b37fd6f88>
    type=xs:dateTime, value=2019-02-01T00:00:00
    type=xs:dateTime, value=2020-01-31T00:00:00
    type=xs:string, value=PROF

<Element {http://v8.1c.ru/8.1/data/core}row at 0x23b37fef048>
    type=xs:dateTime, value=2019-04-15T00:00:00
    type=xs:dateTime, value=2020-04-14T00:00:00
    type=xs:string, value=PROF
```

Comment: Спасибо! Все получилось.

Comment: @klezyk, [чтобы поблагодарить автора ответа, проголосуйте за ответ или отметьте его как решение](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) :)